Excel Ribbon comboBox: always highlight selection
The following code allows you to select from three paper sizes using a comboBox.
There's only one issue regarding the highlighting of the selected item (Excel Mac uses a checkmark). Right now, upon closing and reopening the workbook, the highlighting disappears. You have to select an item for it to reappear.
Is it possible to always show the highlighting (checkmark)?
So that the comboBox keeps the selected item highlighted? So that it behaves like for example the font size box?
Thanks!
' -- XML

<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="LoadRibbon">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab id="Tabv3.1" label="TOOLS" insertAfterMso="TabHome">                                             
                <group id="GroupDemo2" 
                label="SelectPapersize"
                imageMso="AddInManager">
                    <comboBox id="ComboBox001"
                    label="comboBox001"
                    getText="ComboBox001_GetText"
                    onChange="ComboBox001_OnChange">
                        <item id="Item_A3"
                        label="A3"/>
                        <item id="Item_A4"
                        label="A4"/>
                        <item id="Item_A5"
                        label="A5"/>
                    </comboBox>
                </group>   
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>


' -- Callback VBA in Module "RibbonCallbacks"

Option Explicit
Public RibUI As IRibbonUI
Public Const myApp As String = "RibbApp", mySett As String = "Settings", myVal As String = "Value"

Sub LoadRibbon(Ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set RibUI = Ribbon
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "ComboBox001"
End Sub

'Callback for ComboBox001 onChange
Sub ComboBox001_OnChange(control As IRibbonControl, id As String)
    Select Case id
        Case "A3"
             ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA3
        Case "A4"
            ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA4
        Case "A5"
            ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA5
    End Select
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "ComboBox001"
    SaveSetting myApp, mySett, myVal, id
End Sub

'Callback for ComboBox001 getText
Sub ComboBox001_getText(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
  Dim comboVal As String
    comboVal = GetSetting(myApp, mySett, myVal, "No Value") 
    If comboVal <> "No Value" Then
      returnedVal = comboVal
    End If
End Sub


' -- VBA in "ThisWorkbook"

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim idx As String
    Select Case PaperSize
    Case "xlPaperA3"
        idx = "A3"
    Case "xlPaperA4"
        idx = "A4"
    Case "xlPaperA5"
        idx = "A5"
    End Select
    SaveSetting myApp, mySett, myVal, idx
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "ComboBox001"
End Sub



What's the checkmark? Have you tried the solution from your last post?

Just checked: Excel Mac uses a checkmark in front of the selected item, Excel Win simply highlights the selection. So the question should be: how to keep the selection highlighted?

Where do you save the selection when the workbook is closed, and where is the code that loads it back when the workbook is opened?

The getSelectedItemIndex-callback needs to be set in the customUI-XML, and then the callback code needs to be added to the VBA code, with the returnedVal-parameter set to the Id of the item to be selected. The Id-value needs to be stored somewhere, so that it is available after the file is closed and reopened.

Hi OlleSjögren. Thank you. If I add getSelectedItemIndex to the XML, I get an error message: "the attribute is not declared".
